# Fill the last n elements of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I fill the last n cells (inclusive) of a 2d array in java?

This is what I've tried:

```
if(numOfUnusedCells != 0) {
    for (int k = matrix[0].length; k >= numOfUnusedCells; k--) {
        matrix[rows-1][k -1] = "*";
    }
}
```

Example

for a 2d array as such as 2 elements to fill:

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   | * | * |
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill random numbers in a 2D array for column/row addition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839715/fill-random-numbers-in-a-2d-array-for-column-row-addition)

Comment: Can you draw a small table to emphasize what you try to achieve?

Comment: Nope - not a duplicate question, at least not that duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Arrays.fill](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int)) can do that for you:

see this example where you can fill the 1st element of the array with -21

## example:

```
final int[][] a2dArr = new int[3][3];
System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.deepToString(a2dArr));
for (int i = 0; i < a2dArr.length; i++) {
      Arrays.fill(a2dArr[i], 0, 1, -21);
}
 System.out.println("After: " + Arrays.deepToString(a2dArr));
```

Comment: Thats a nice one. I dont see much sense in the big font "example" text though.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the help.